# skypeforlinux 8.13.0.2 (still) fails to start on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, skype

There is already [a Microsoft Community thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/skype-for-linux-81302-fails-to-start-ubuntu-1404/0a880c7f-da0a-4091-99e8-02cb91c07be7?auth=1) on my question, but I still do not know what to do to activate upgraded Skype on Ubuntu 14.04. On the thread, the suggestion is to downgrade by

```
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux=8.11.0.4
```

Is this working? Or shall I wait for repair by Microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue today morning, after upgrading skype it was not loading I was seeing white screen only.

So, Actually your command in question did the trick with little bit of extra efforts.

What I did is :

```
sudo apt-get purge skypeforlinux 
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux=8.11.0.4
```

Purge will purge all skype data also, so after installing specific down version, it will work.

Comment: Personally, on Linux Mint 17.3 KDE (based on Ubuntu 14.04.x), the remove/purge of the newest version step was not necessary. Tried this at least a couple of times (in which I upgraded->downgraded->upgraded again to try another solution->downgraded as a final temporary solution). So, I just needed the already mentioned install command:

    sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux=8.11.0.4

Comment: May be you're right, but on mine it was not working by `apt-get remove`, so I purged. I forgot to mention, mine is Ubuntu Trusty (14.04)

Comment: E: Version '8.11.0.4' for 'skypeforlinux' was not found :-( Newer versions don't work

Answer (score 0):

Installing Preview version (8.16.76.1) via snap from insider channel solved the problem for me (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo snap install --channel insider/stable --classic skype
```